# TornadoFX: Label not updating

Tags: tornadofx

I have an application where I'm transforming an XML document using XSL transformation (XSLT). This is build using TornadoFX (source code can be found [here](https://github.com/bohsen/xslt-xml)). I'm trying to update a status label with the status of the transformation, which is done inside a class that extends Controller. But for some reason, the status label shows nothing.

The source for my transformer class:

```
class Transformer : Controller() {
    private val statusProperty = SimpleStringProperty("")
    var status by statusProperty

    fun transform(xml: File, xslt: File, result: StreamResult) {
        runLater { status = "" }

        // create the DOM Source
        val factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
        factory.isNamespaceAware = true
        val builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder()
        val bbcDoc = builder.parse(xml)
        val source = DOMSource(bbcDoc)

        // Create an instance of the TransformerFactory
        val transfomerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
        val transformer = transfomerFactory.newTransformer(StreamSource(xslt))
                .apply {
                    setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes")
                    setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4")
                }
        runLater {
            try {
                transformer.transform(source, result)
                status = "Completed successful"
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                status = e.message
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The mainscreen class:

```
class MainScreen : View("XSLT Transformer") {

    val status: TaskStatus by inject()
    val model: TransformerModel by inject()
    val transformer: Transformer by inject()

    private val xmlFilter = arrayOf(FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("XML Filer (*.xml)", "*.xml"))

    private val xsltFilter = arrayOf(FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("XSLT Filer (*.xslt)", "*.xslt"))
    private lateinit var xmlInput: TextField
    private lateinit var xsltInput: TextField

    override val root = form {
        fieldset(labelPosition = Orientation.VERTICAL) {
            field("XSLT fil") {
                ...
            }
            field("XML Input Fil") {
                ...
            }
            button("Konverter") {
                enableWhen(model.valid)
                isDefaultButton = true
                useMaxWidth = true
                action {
                    // An object to hold the results. It can be a file.
//                    val writer = System.out
                    val output = StreamResult(StringWriter())
                    runAsyncWithProgress {
                        try {
                            transformer.status = "Konverterer xml fil..."
                            transformer.transform(File(xmlInput.text), File(xsltInput.text), output)
                            transformer.status = "Færdig"
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            transformer.status = e.message
                        }
                    } ui {
                        showDialogResult(output)
                        transformer.status = "Completed"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        label(transformer.status) {
            style {
                paddingTop = 10
                textFill = Color.RED
                fontWeight = FontWeight.BOLD
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must bind to `transformer.statusProperty`, not to `transformer.status`. The `status` property is simply a getter/setter and have no way of updating the label. The `statusProperty` howevere is an observable, so changes to it will reflect in the label.

You must also make sure not to perform long running tasks on the UI thread. `runLater` schedules work to be done on the UI thread. What you want to do is to perform the long running tasks in a `runAsync` block and add a `ui` block which receives the result. In the `ui` block you can update the UI.